McVittie in Schwarzschild coordinates
I am trying to get McVittie's metric to Schwarzschild's as a homework. In flat geometry ($k=0$) it is given by:
$$ds^2 = -\left(\frac{\mu_-}{\mu_+}\right)^2c^2dt^2 + \left(\mu_+\right)^4a(t)^2\left(dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2{\theta}d\varphi^2\right)$$
Where
$$\mu_\pm = 1 \pm \frac{GM}{2c^2a(t)r}$$
I started with the coordinate transformation $r' = ar$ and, using
$$g'_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x'^\nu}g_{\rho\sigma}$$
Due to
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial r'} = \frac{1}{a}; \qquad \frac{\partial ct}{\partial r'} = 0; \qquad \frac{\partial r}{\partial ct'} = \frac{-r'\dot{a}}{a^2}$$
I get
$$ds^2 = -\left[\left(\frac{\mu'_-}{\mu'_+}\right)^2 - \frac{r'\dot{a}}{c^2a}\left(\mu'_+\right)^4\right]c^2dt^2 + \left(\mu'_+\right)^4\left(dr'^2 + r'^2d\theta^2 + r'^2\sin^2{\theta}d\varphi^2\right)$$
Now with
$$\mu'_\pm = 1 \pm \frac{GM}{2c^2r'}$$
But I don't know how to proceed further. If you want to remove the isotropy that would be done with
$$r = r'\left(\mu'_+\right)^2$$
Which successfully removes $\left(\mu'_+\right)^4$ from $d\theta^2$ and $d\varphi^2$ components, but I don't know how to exactly proceed with the $dr'^2$ and $c^2dt^2$. I can't see how
$$\left(\mu'_+\right)^4 \longrightarrow \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}}$$
Or
$$\left(\frac{\mu'_-}{\mu'_+}\right)^2 \longrightarrow 1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}$$
Can anyone help me compute the answer? Is this the final result?
$$ds^2 = -\left[1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r} - \frac{r^2\dot{a}^2}{c^2a^2}\right]c^2dt^2 + \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}}dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2{\theta}d\varphi^2$$
I assume the result should be Schwarzschild-de Sitter, but it doesn’t appear in my calculations D:

Let us start with the metric that you have, with setting $c=1$, suppressing the $t$ dependence of the scale factor and condensing the angular variables:
$$ ds^2 = -\left(\frac{\mu_-}{\mu_+}\right)^2dt^2+\mu_+^4a^2(dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2)\,.
$$
To reduce to Schwarzschild, we first need to relabel the radial coordinate that sits in front of the $d\Omega^2$. So, we choose
$$
 R = \mu_+^2 a r\,,
\\
dR = \mu_+\left(\mu_+ (a dr +ar H dt)-M\left(Hdt+\frac{dr}{r}\right)\right)\,,
$$
where $H = \frac{\dot{a}}{a}$. After some cleaning up we find
$$
dr= \frac{dR}{\mu_-\mu_+ a} - Hr dt\,.
$$
Plugging this in to our metric we find
$$
ds^2 = -\left(\left(\frac{\mu_-}{\mu_+}\right)^2-H^2R^2\right)dt^2+ \left(\frac{\mu_-}{\mu_+}\right)^{-2} dR^2+R^2d\Omega^2 -\frac{2 HR\, dt\, dR}{(\mu_-/\mu_+)}\,.
$$
Now, we make an observation(with an aim to reduce it to Schwarzschild metric in mind)
$$
\left(\frac{\mu_-}{\mu_+}\right)^2 = 1-\frac{2M}{R}\,.
$$
with this our metric becomes
$$
ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{R}-H^2R^2\right)dt^2 +\frac{dR^2}{1-\frac{2M}{R}}+R^2d\Omega^2-\frac{2HR\,dt\,dR}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{R}}}\,.
$$
And we our done after one last relabeling
$$
dT = dt +\frac{H R\,dR}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{R}}\left(1-\frac{2M}{R}-H^2R^2\right)}\,,
$$
which gives us
$$
ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{R}-H^2R^2\right)dT^2 + \frac{dR^2}{\left(1-\frac{2M}{R}-H^2R^2\right)} +R^2d\Omega^2\,.
$$

Good explanation :D. It still looks like a bit of magic to me the $\left(\mu_- / \mu_+\right)^2 = 1 - 2M/R$, but since working forward from Schwarzschild to Isotropic that's what you get I trust it's true.
